# How to log amount of data transferred (upload / download)

Tags: windows-7, vmware, bandwidth, network-monitoring

What is the easiest way to keep track of much data is transferred? I'm interested in knowing the amount uploaded and downloaded over a certain time frame (i.e. the past day or week).

It would be for a guest operating system, Windows 7, running in VMware workstation. I'd prefer the easiest solution so if one's built into Windows or VMware I'd like that, otherwise is there a simple program that can do this?

Answer (score 0):

*Free*: **[NetWorx](https://www.softperfect.com/products/networx/)** is a simple and free, yet powerful tool that helps you objectively evaluate your bandwidth consumption situation. You can use it to **collect bandwidth usage data** and measure the speed of your Internet or any other network connections. **Usage reports**, exportable to a variety of file formats, including Excel, MS Word and HTML.

Check out [this tutorial](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/43561/ask-how-to-geek-how-can-i-monitor-my-bandwidth-usage/) for getting started with NetWorx.

[image]

*Paid*: **[Bandwidth Monitor](http://www.bwmonitor.com/)** monitors bandwidth usages through computer it's installed on. The software displays real-time download and upload speeds in graphical and numerical forms (refer to screen shot below), logs bandwidth usages, and provides **daily, weekly and monthly bandwidth usage reports**.

[image]